# finding string length and storing in dict

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a sample list

```
a = ['be','see','tree'....]
```

The user will provide a `raw_input` as name. Then, it has to print the name along with each and every word in the list, then need to find the total number of characters for the name along with each and every word in list.

Atlast, I need to store it in a dictionary.

Eg:-
`raw_input` `name` = `'jean'`, then it has to print:

```
jean be
jean see
jean tree
```

I then need to store in dictionary as :-

```
{'jean be':'6','jean see':'7','jean tree':'8'}
```

My coding:

```
a=['be','see','tree']
x = raw_input("Enter the query x ")
for item in a:
    length =len(item[i] + x)
```

I am not sure,how far it is correct and I dont know how to store it in a dict.

Comment: Well, you need to create a dict.  Have you looked into how to do that?

Comment: Your `for` loop gives you each element in the list `a` directly. There is no need to use `item[i]` when you can just use `item` *directly*. Start with `print(x, item)` and move from there.

Comment: The [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) tells you everything you need to know about dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension for save your items in a dictionary :

```
>>> inp=raw_input()
>>> {inp+' '+i:len(inp+i) for i in a}
{'jean see': 7, 'jean be': 6, 'jean tree': 8}
```

and use a `for` loop to print the desire pairs :

```
>>> for i in a:
...   print inp+' '+i
... 
jean be
jean see
jean tree
```

But as dictionaries are not ordered you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for create an ordered dict:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> D=OrderedDict()
>>> for k,v in sorted(((inp+' '+i,len(inp+i)) for i in a),key=lambda x:x[1]):
...   D[k]=v
... 
>>> D
OrderedDict([('jean be', 6), ('jean see', 7), ('jean tree', 8)])
```

Comment: This won't print the desired output, nor is this helpful to the OP's current level of understanding.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Your error is to try using `item[i]` (`i` is undefined anyway) when you have access to `item`. Check this out:

```
a=['be','see','tree']
x = raw_input("Enter the query x ")
d = dict()
for item in a:
    d[x + ' ' + item] = len(x + item)

print d
```

Comment: It is preferred to use `{}`, not `dict()`, to create an empty dictionary.

Comment: I don't think there is a general consensus on `{}` vs `dict()`. PyCharm IDE for example encourages using the constructor variant.

Comment: Using the function requires an extra global name lookup, the literal won't.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=['be','see','tree']
somedict = {}
x = raw_input("Enter the query x ")
for i in a:
    neww = x+" "+i
    print neww
    somedict[neww] = len(neww)
print somedict
```

Output :

```
Enter the query x {'john tree': 9, 'john be': 7, 'john see': 8}
```

Comment: Where are you printing the combinations?

Comment: Edited it to the OP requirements. (Cant believe THE MartijnPieters commented on my answer)

Comment: @letsc he wouldn't be _The_ MartijnPieters if he weren't everywhere-at-once on the Python tag :P